# When we pass # instead of an Integer in url path parameter , why does it accept '#' in place of an Integer?

Tags: java, url, integer

while doing get operation in spring boot application, 
like `api/getbooks/1` : it fetches the first record.
for `api/getbooks/@` : gives invalid parameter.
but `api/getbooks/1#` : gives the same result as api/getbooks/1.
how can i make it not to accept #?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article of URL fragments on Wikipedia can find

> The fragment identifier functions differently to the rest of the URI:
>   its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from
>   the web server, ...
>   When an agent requests a web resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment

So that is basically the intended behavior the # and everything afterwards is not sent to server. So the URL server gets is the same for both queries.